# Unable to do data backup in GridDB

Tags: griddb

So I have been working with GridDB and using it for multiple projects. But recently, I received an error while backing up my data. I follow the commands mentioned below to usually fully backup my data and check its status:

```
$ gs_backup -u admin/admin 2023025 # 2023025 is the directory

$ gs_stat -u admin/admin --type backup # Backup Status Check
BackupStatus: Processing
```

But instead of receiving the backup status as "Completed" or "Processing," I constantly get the following error:

```
[Server]: 10011

[Description] (Backup error detected)

[Format] (*Master node only) Partition no., owner address, owner LSN, backup address, backup LSN
```

I even started restarting the cluster, but it did not help. So, any idea why do I keep getting this error?

P.S. The node configuration for my cluster is as follows:

```
$ cat /var/lib/gridstore/conf/gs_node.json         # example of configuration check
{
        "dataStore":{
                "dbPath":"/var/lib/gridstore/data",
                "backupPath":"/mnt/gridstore/backup",      # backup directory
                "storeMemoryLimit":"1024",
                "concurrency":2,
                "logWriteMode":1,
                "persistencyMode":"NORMAL"                
　　　　　　:
　　　　　　:
}
```